# Windows Media Based video audio converter?

Tags: video, audio, conversion, streaming, codec

This may seem like an odd question. Right now ONLY windows media player, VLC and media player classic opens and plays my audio video correctly. Virtualdub plays it back with the wrong framerate and losses the audio, Avidemux 2.5 seems to be able to dump the audio/video but the video (like all other apps) is either a bad framerate or is wrong (glitches and bad framerate or bad dump). Nothing recognizes the audio file and when playing the video Avidemux (and most other things) die. FFMPEG cant seem to split the video or audio (using copy -an and etc) and this is getting me very angry. VLC dumps the video incorrectly when i try dumping it with that too.

What can i use to convert the video? its streaming so it starts at 26mins in and ends at 28 (this is where apps have the problem. They dont know this and fudge everything or crash). I manage to dump the audio with Avidemux but virtualdub and ffmpeg says unreconized codec. Even if i cant convert it (it seems compressed enough) i want to at least attach it back into an AVI.

Comment: What does GSpot say about your video? ( http://www.free-codecs.com/download/GSpot.htm )

Comment: streaming transports are different from standard a/v data containers -- you may have to tell your tools specifically that it's a streaming transport.  they're choking now probably because they're trying to process a standard a/v format and the data isn't layed out like that.  where'd it come from?  did you capture it with something?  what do WMP/MPC/VLC tell you about it while they're playing?  any info will help the tools extract it correctly.

Comment: harrymc: http://i35.tinypic.com/2eg4jdg.jpg
~quack: VLC reports it as FLV1 and NELL audio. I dont think it mentions anything about streaming. mediaplayer knows it is and vlc just reports it X minutes in and plays the remainder. I capture the data on my own with jaksta which cant convert it itself (it uses ffmpeg). I'm considering hunting down professional apps and hope they can handle streaming and all other data.

Answer (score 1):

my converter of choice:

**[SUPER ©](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html)** Simplified Universal Player Encoder & Renderer.

i have tried so many but have yet to find a match for SUPER. it yields best results and is truly universal, as it can handle pretty much any media format under the sun.

Comment: "SUPER © Simplified Universal Player Encoder & Renderer. A GUI to FFmpeg, MEncoder, MPlayer, x264, [...] plugIn."  It's ffmpeg based so no guarantees, but it probably installs its own ffmpeg backend so it may work better than others tried before.