# Proffesional video editor that can handle FLV?

Tags: video, conversion, editing

I tried Adobe Premiere Pro CS3 and was not able to open my file (unsupported format). Media player can open it thanks to ffdshow (tryouts IIRC). Premiere doesnt seem to want to use ffdshow. I tried renaming it to AVI and hoped Premiere would open it via ffdshow but it didnt and i checked and disabled the dont use ffdshow option in ffdshow video decoder option.

What is a good proffesional video editor that can handle FLV? All ffmpeg based editors died on it and virtualdub got close but had a bad framerate. Probably bc it didnt know it was a streaming vid and the start is 26mins of 31min video. More info here but what can i use to open and properly convert flv video [Windows Media Based video audio converter?](https://superuser.com/questions/50779/windows-media-based-video-audio-converter)

Comment: Wait a minute, isn't ffdshow based on ffmpeg? If ffdshow can play the video, then ffmpeg should be able to transcode it. I'm not an expert here, but I know that ffmpeg's stable releases are few and far between, so a lot of the running ffmpeg code out there is based on development shapshots. In particular, the ffdshow plugin you have might be based on a different version of ffmpeg from everything else. You might want to look into that.

Comment: I think the difference is the way it transcode and not the actual decoding.

Someone helped me solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

The best success I had was using [MPlayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/) to transcode the streams to uncompressed MPEG, a much more usable format.

Another option is using [GraphEdit](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/GraphEdit), a tool bundled with DX and allows you to load modules and manually reroute pins through codecs. You get mixed results though. There's a GPL remake called [GraphStudio](http://blog.monogram.sk/janos/tools/monogram-graphstudio/), haven't used that yet.

I haven't found a single solid method yet, it's always this or that when working with flv.

PS. I feel your pain, FLV has caused me many headaches too. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

FLV is a container format, so the simplest solution may be to put the data into another container format that your program *does* understand. IF the audio and video *codecs* used in your FLV files are not recognized by your program, then you've got a more complicated problem, and you'll have to transcode them (for which purpose my personal preference is Handbrake).

If you'll clarify whether the problem is containers or codecs and then leave a comment on my answer so SU notifies me, I can reply with more details.

Comment: Problem is EVERYTHING fails. Handbrake gets errors along with ffmpeg. virtualdub gets the wrong framerate and cannot access sounds. I tried one FLV app to split the audio and video but with no luck (it was free). Some apps was able to convert it but the size was horribly big AND there were problems or some kind of glitches (framerate or audio usually)

Comment: based on his linked question, it's FLV1 vid and NELL audio (Nellymoser Asao codec: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nellymoser_Asao_Codec ..) according to wikipedia this codec is supported by recent ffmpeg (>=v0.5), but who knows how good the support is.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Sorry, just read your other question that you've already tried VLC.
I'll leave this here to no-one else suggests it.

You can use VLC to transcode most formats. If you reduce it to some basic format mpeg, Adobe Premiere should probably be able to read that correctly.

Some info on [transcoding](http://wiki.videolan.org/Transcode) [through](http://www.videolan.org/doc/videolan-howto/en/ch09.html) VLC from the faq.